# Disposing of Streams/XmlReaders within a custom pipeline

Tags: c#, biztalk, aspose.words

I'm creating a custom receive pipeline in BizTalk that will take in a message which contains a  word document as a base64 string. This will extract the string from a node set in the pipeline configuration into a memoryStream and pass it over to Apose.Words to convert it to PDF and save it to a file.

The base64 string is removed from the message and the updated message is then assigned back to the message body. The path to the newly created file is then promoted in the message.

My issue is that the host running this pipeline is increasing in memory and doesn't seem to release any resources. Currently it's running at 250MB and doesn't go down. This is causing issues as subsequent calls don't process in time.

### My code

Pipeline component:

```
public Microsoft.BizTalk.Message.Interop.IBaseMessage Execute(IPipelineContext pContext, Microsoft.BizTalk.Message.Interop.IBaseMessage pInMsg)
    {
        string fileName = GenerateFileName();

        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(pInMsg.BodyPart.GetOriginalDataStream());
        var removeNodeReader = new StoreAndRemoveReader(reader, nodeNameOfEncodedFileContents, fileName);

        XmlTranslatorStream translatorStream = new XmlTranslatorStream(removeNodeReader);

        pInMsg.Context.Write(contextKeyForDocumentFilePath, contextNSForDocumentFilePath, fileName);

        pInMsg.BodyPart.Data = translatorStream;

        return pInMsg;          
    }
```

StoreAndRemoveReader:
(This was taken from http://biztalkmessages.vansplunteren.net/articles/dealing-with-base64/)

```
public class StoreAndRemoveReader : XmlReader
{
    private bool inAttribute;
    private XmlReader wrappedReader;
    private string nodeNameOfEncodedFileContents;
    private string documentFilePath;

    public StoreAndRemoveReader(XmlReader wrappedReader,
                                    string nodeNameOfEncodedFileContents,
                                    string documentFilePath)
    {
        this.wrappedReader = wrappedReader;

        this.nodeNameOfEncodedFileContents = nodeNameOfEncodedFileContents;
        this.documentFilePath = documentFilePath;
    }

    public override bool Read()
    {
        Boolean result = wrappedReader.Read();

        if (wrappedReader.IsStartElement() && wrappedReader.LocalName == nodeNameOfEncodedFileContents)
        {
            if (wrappedReader.IsEmptyElement)
            {
                wrappedReader.Read();
            }
            else
            {
                Base64DecodeDocument(wrappedReader);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private void Base64DecodeDocument(XmlReader reader)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
        int readBytes = 0;

        //FileStream outputFile = new FileStream(this.documentFilePath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write);


        using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream(307200))
        {
           BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(outputStream);

           while ((readBytes = reader.ReadElementContentAsBase64(buffer, 0, 1000)) > 0)
           {
              bw.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
           }

            //File.WriteAllText(this.documentFilePath, "test");
           WordToPDFConversion.ConvertWordDocumentToPdf(outputStream, this.documentFilePath);
        }
    }
```

### Attempts to fix

I've tried using statements in the pipeline component on the XmlTextReader and StoreAndRemoveReader but this didn't work as I assume that it closes the stream of the incoming message.

I've tried running Aspose standalone and it does use a lot of memory, however it does clear it up after.

### In summary:

Can I dispose of the Readers in my pipeline component, or is there a better way to be extracting the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was too engrossed with the memory usage that i ignored CPU usage of the host while attempting to do the pdf conversion. I've added an extra BizTalk server to share the load and CPU usage has gone from 95%~ on a single server to about 10%~ on each.

Answer (score 1):

250MB isn't extraordinarily large.  Did you check for Throttling?

Also, is there a reason to initialize a 300MB MemoryStream?  MemoryStream is auto-magically expandable.

Suggestions:

1. Use VirtualStream instead of MemoryStream to trade memory for disk.
2. Maybe you could just use a FileStream.

If you really wanted to get clever, you could wrap the ReadElementContentAsBase64 operation again in a Stream interface.  But I don't think you need to go that far.

Comment: It's initialising to 300K, I believe this can help with performance by preallocating? I know the data will be at least this size.

I've changed to a VirtualStream instead which made a slight difference, but what's fixed the issue is using an extra server (see my answer)

Comment: Yeah, you're right, 300k.  I must have mistyped something.